# How to upload csv file by class.upload.php?

Tags: php, csv, file-upload

I am using upload php class from this site: http://www.verot.net/

Image upload is working fine. But when I try to upload csv file it throughs an error:

```
getimagesize(): Read error! [APP\Vendor\class.upload.php, line 2423]
```

Here is my code:

```
   $upload = new Upload($file['file']);
            $upload->no_script = false;
            $upload->allowed = array('application/msword');
            $upload->file_new_name_body = 'data';       
            $upload->process($this->target_path);
            if (!$upload->processed) {
                $msg = $this->generateError($upload->error);
                $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
```

Here $file has the all info of attached file.
If I try to upload an image it works fine but when I try to upload a csv file it shows error. I set the mime-type. But no luck. Anyone have this experience. Or is there any plugin like verot.net to upload file. Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Make sure that the path defined in `$this->target_path` is readable/writable by Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial guides you trought file uploading process:

[W3Schools: File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

File uploading is not very hard, so I suggest you to try learning it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your class file is meant to upload or resize image files only.

It will not work for other extensions like .csv, .txt or any other text file or non image file.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching answer to your same question and got that this class should work fine with any other file upload . You just need to set the following for all files other than image

```
$upload->mime_getimagesize = false;
```

This will not throw the error you mentioned for non image files